# how to check if url param entered exist in location.pathname via React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Well, I try to understand legacy code with React routes onboard.

I have an url like

```
/home/reports/some_report_numbers
```

when user changes the ulr like that:

```
/home/reports/some_report_numb
```

I want to check if "some_report_numb" exists in props, in `this.props.location.pathname`. If exists - fine, go that way, otherwise go another way.

Maybe it is a wrong approach at all? Well, when the report is shown and user just deletes some letters in url I need to redirect to /home/ page. To do that I need somehow to check if that report with that numbers exists at all.

Maybe it could be done via

```
<Route name={SomeRouteName} path='reports/:reportId' component={HomePage} />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of `react-router-dom`

Link: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

`match` become an object that can be used in your component. Like explain in the documentation, you have access to `match` object with the following steps:

- `Route component` as `this.props.match`
- `Route render` as `({ match }) => ()`
- `Route children` as `({ match }) => ()`
- `withRouter` as `this.props.match`
- `matchPath` as the `return value`

For example, if you have the following route:

```
<Route path="/reports/:reportId" component={HomePage} />
```

In your component, you can access to this with: `this.props.match` because it's an object and inside it, you will have what you want.

After that, you could check what params you have in your URL.

Now, if you want to redirect the user, you can use `<Redirect to={'/your/path'} />`

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've tried it, but `console.log(this.props.match);` returned me undefined

Comment: Have you connected your component with the `withRouter` ?

Comment: I have `import { withRouter } from "react-router";` in my Router.js and  `render: function() {
        const {match} = this.props;` Anything else needed?

Comment: So, if we take your code from the beginning, with `<Route />`

And if you want to triggered params in your URL, the documentation uses match like this : `function Topics({ match }) { }`

You can now use it as a props. 

I don't know if I am clear, this is my first time on stackoverflow

This is the **Source** https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic